# Google Play 3rd Party Payment Allowed?

Tags: android, legal, mobile, payment, google-play

Does Google allow 3rd party payment solutions to be enabled in developers' apps (i.e., Paypal, carrier/SMS payment), especially in countries where Google Checkout isn't present? Or does this violate any policy of theirs?

Please reference the policy in your answer if you can, and thanks in advance to all who answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their [help pages](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=105916):

> You can make purchases through Google Wallet using a credit, debit, or
>   gift card with the following logos:
>
> American Express(USD Only)
>   Discover (USD Only) 
>   MasterCard
>   Visa
>   Visa Electron (Outside of US Only)

However, some customers may be able to set up payment [through their mobile carrier](https://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=167794) and people can put money into their Google Wallet with [gift cards](http://play.google.com/about/giftcards/) purchased in store (or online).

---

My answer above is how users can get money into their Google Play account from 3rd party sources. I guess I misunderstood the question.

If you're selling a game on Google Play, you have to use Google Play for in-app purchases, as stated in the [Google Play content policy](http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html):

> - **In-app purchases:** Developers offering additional content, services or
>     functionality within an application downloaded from Google Play must
>     use Google Play's payment system as the method of payment, except:
>
>   - where payment is primarily for physical goods or services (e.g. buying
>       movie tickets; e.g. buying a publication where the price also includes
>       a hard copy subscription);
>   - or where payment is for digital content or
>       goods that may be consumed outside of the application itself (e.g.
>       buying songs that can be played on other music players)

Comment: The question appears to be about whether an app in the Play Store is permitted to use other payment processors, not what Google Play itself supports.

Comment: My answer was how to get money into the account from 3rd parties. I've updated to include more information.

Comment: I'd remove the first part of this answer, since the only real answer is the second part...

Comment: [Dumb question]: that last point, if I also have an iOS app, would that be  the ability consume outside of this [google play] application itself" ?

Comment: @Hobbamok Only if you were trying to sell your iOS app from inside your Android app, which would be sort of odd. In that case, you'd likely be redirecting them to the iOS store page to buy it there.